# Etymology of "ripsnorter"?

Tags: etymology

[Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=ripsnorter) doesn't expound the etymology, and states no more than:

> "something of exceptional strength," 1840, probably from [rip](https://www.etymonline.com/word/rip?ref=etymonline_crossreference) (v.) + [snort](https://www.etymonline.com/word/snort?ref=etymonline_crossreference) (q.v.).

Does anyone have any more detail on the origins of this word?

Comment: Is the "exceptional strength" referring to potency (i.e. of a drink) or physical prowess?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"Ripsnorter" is likely to have originated in the 19th century when such novel words as "rambunctious" and "stemwinder" were considered humorous. They are sometimes cited as evidence of the robust and inventive U.S. culture of the time.

Answer (score 1):

Eric Partridge lists it as

> **rip-snorter** Anything exceptionally good; an eccentric or very entertaining person: Australian: since ca. 1910. Baker. Adopted from U.S.

[From *A Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional English*, Seventh Edition, p. 1368 (supplement)]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is related to the **SNORT** of somebody who was caught off guard by something entirely hilarious.

A sneeze or a snort could *wrack* your body, or *rip* through it.